# circular on border of table with text in that

Tags: html, css

i have big challenge in html css in create custom table[image]

I have no idea in this case for create 
I want create circular on vertical line of border
I create this table . but these to are very Different :-D

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    
}
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="circle">test</div>
      </div>
    </td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are on right track just a little bit of changes in `left` and some `padding` on `td`

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    
}
th, td {
    padding: 16px;
}
td{
 padding-right: 22px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -38px;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 37px;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th> 
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td><div class="container">
                <div class="circle">
              test
                </div>
              </div></td> 
            <td>94</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td><div class="container">
                <div class="circle">
              test
                </div>
              </div></td> 
            <td>94</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td><div class="container">
                <div class="circle">
              test
                </div>
              </div></td> 
            <td>94</td>
          </tr>


      </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code

try that :

```html
<html>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th> 
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td style="width: 100px;height: 100px;">      <div class="row">
                <div class="large-8 large-centered">
                  <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="vertical-line"></div> 
                    <div class="circle">
                      <h5>Some Text</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="vertical-line"></div> 
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td> 
            <td>94</td>
          </tr>


      </table>


      <style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    
}
.wrapper {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

h5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
  color: #000000;
}

.vertical-line {
  width: 2px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #2ecc71;
  margin: 0 auto 0 ;
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #333;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
}
      </style>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `container` is of `100%` and that `left` is correct:

```
<html>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th> 
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td><div class="container">
                <div class="circle">
              test
                </div>
              </div></td> 
            <td>94</td>
          </tr>


      </table>



      <style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -20px;
}

      </style>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the `calc(-20px)` do at the end?

Comment: @Paul it pushes .circle to the left by 20px. The calc is unnecessary, it's enough to have left: -20px;. I edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Ah! Okay.  I thought there may be some mystical meaning to the `calc()`.

Comment: @Paul no, nothing special. I just forgot that the formula inside calc was trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I created a working demo. It is fully working.

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    
}
.main-container{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  flex:2;
}

.container:before, .container:after {
    content: "";
    background: #000;
    width: 1px;
    height: 20px;
}

.circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>
      <div class="main-container">
        <div style="flex:1">
          <div>Monday</div>
          <div>March 6, 2020</div>
          <div>from Tokyo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
           <div class="circle">test</div>
        </div>
         <div>
          <div>Monday</div>
          <div>March 6, 2020</div>
          <div>from Tokyo</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td> 
    <td>94</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem because the table cell containing the circles cannot contain any content.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? Note that in order for this to work reliably, I gave your table row (the `tr` element) a fixed height.

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
 height: 10px;
}

.firstRow { 
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.circle {
  position:absolute;

  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 50%;

  top: -30px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: calc(100%);
  
}

.circleText {
  text-align: center; 
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  top: 20px;
  transform: translateY(50%); 
}
```

```html
<html>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th> 
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve
              <div class="firstRow">
                <div class="circle">
                      <div class="circleText">test</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
                
            <td>Eve's last name</td>
            <td>94</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The key lessons here are:

- an extra relatively positioned element is not necessary for absolutely positioning the circle. we can just put the `position: relative` on the `<td>` itself.
- use `transform: translate()` to position the circle elements without need for arbitrary pixel values

This solution uses the least CSS possible and standard (semantic) `<table>` markup

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: solid 1px #666;
  padding: 2em 4em;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  background: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #aaa;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>XYZ</td>
    <td>
      MAR 2
      <span class="circle">
        10<br>Days
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>MAR 11</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>
      MAR 6
      <span class="circle">
        20<br>Days
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>MAR 15</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/arajay/pen/YzPrQLG)